# Get the data from month wise different tables which are created dynamically

Tags: mysql

I have following tables:

```
vbSuccessful_630
vbSuccessful_631
vbSuccessful_632
```

...so on which are month wise tables. I need to get the data according to date range which will select the required tables dynamically.

```
SELECT SUM(Duration/60) 
FROM vbSuccessful_632, vbSuccessful_631
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(connectTime/1000, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '2021-11-19 14:50:00' AND '2021-12-20 14:51:59';
```

Can anyone suggest how should I keep all required tables under **FROM** that is related to my search range.

Comment: Either normalize your structure (preferred - multiple tables per entity is wrong practice) or use dynamic SQL.

Comment: *`FROM vbSuccessful_632, vbSuccessful_631`* - this is wrong. You need in UNION ALL, not in cartesian which is CROSS JOIN.

Comment: @Akina UNION ALL will give row wise output from all the selected tables. If I have hundreds of tables then output will come in 100 rows. I need a sum result from all tables as all tables are containing same column names. BTW, I have no write access to change the DB structure.

Comment: 'If I have hundreds of tables then output will come in 100 rows' - union in sub query and sum in main query - nb that's the price you pay for the design..

Comment: *If I have hundreds of tables* ... and each table contains at least 2 rows then your server will die while trying to obtain 2^100 combined rows due to your cartesian.